# Python, Tkinter: evaluate strings as objects with same name so attributes can be used

Tags: python, sqlite, loops, tkinter

Using python, tkinter:

I create entry boxes using a loop as follows:

```
    list_a = ['FACILITYCODE','FACILITYNAME','Owner','RegionDescription','Territory','DMA','ADDRESSONE','CITY', 'STATEABBREVIATION','ZIPCODE']

    global temp_rows_var2
    temp_rows_var2 = 0
    global temp_cols_var2
    temp_cols_var2 = 0
    for i in list_a:
            globals()[i + "label"] = Label(editor_frame2,text=str(i))
            globals()[i + "label"].grid(row=temp_rows_var2,column=temp_cols_var2)
            globals()[i + "entry"] = Entry(editor_frame2,width=20)
            globals()[i + "entry"].grid(row=temp_rows_var2+1,column=temp_cols_var2)
            temp_cols_var2 +=1
```

Now I want to get the data from those entry boxes, so I'm looping through again.
(I know this is wrong but it will show you what I'm trying to do)

```
    new_temp_list = []
    for i in list_a:
           new_temp_list.append([i+"entry"].get())
```

Result is AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

How can I get python to read that string as a object with that exact same name so I can use the .get() on it?

I have tried exec() to no avail. Same with eval(). I feel like it's gotta be one of those.

Thanks all!

Comment: don't you have to reference `globals()` in order to get the value? for example: `new_temp_list.append(globals()[i+"entry"].get())`

Comment: Jeepers dude, looks like that worked. I thought I already tried that and was getting that AttributeError. Anyway. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 3):

You should not do this. If you want to use symbolic names, save the widgets to a dictionary or list.

```
entries = []
labels = []
for i in list_a:
    label = Label(editor_frame2,text=str(i))
    entry = Entry(editor_frame2,width=20)
    label.grid(row=temp_rows_var2,column=temp_cols_var2)
    entry.grid(row=temp_rows_var2+1,column=temp_cols_var2)
    temp_cols_var2 +=1

    entries.append(entry)
    labels.append(label)
```

With that, you can access the entries via their index:

```
new_temp_list = []
for i in list_a:
       new_temp_list.append(entries[i].get())
```